# how select a node after load the form ? for sample select node14

Tags: forms, select, treeview, load

```
private void box_kol_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        TreeNode n = new TreeNode("دسته بندی دفاتر");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(n);
        LoadTreeviewNode(n);
        treeView1.ExpandAll();
```

I need to select the sample node 14 after loading the form

[image]

How can I select the sample node 14 after loading the form.

I wrote treeview1.selectednode = 14;
but I get an error

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode' portal

Comment: my code i : treeView1.SelectedNode = 14;

Comment: @Matthias if can help me